# Как найти нужный html тег в переменной

Tags: php, html

Возник вопрос как найти нужный мне тег в переменной например есть `$string;` и мне нужно найти в нем тег `<readmore>` или `<a name=""></a>` к примеру.

Задача такая. В переменной например 120 символов и тег находится на 61 месте как посчитать количество символов до этого тега.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php Библиотека для работы с html. Забудьте про регулярки для этого

Answer (score 6):

Если честно, то постановка задачи довольно таки странная... Это точно случай из жизни? Или сферический пример в вакууме? ))

Для вашего случая. так как он описан - решение крайне простое:

- [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php)`($string, <readmore>)`;

Если все таки вам надо что-то потом с текстом делать, советую обратить внимание на:

- [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php)`("/<a name=.+\/a>/", $string, $match)`; - в `$match` будет результат вхождения маски шаблона;
- [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)`("/<a name=.+\/a>/", "Текст, на который меняем", $string)`;

Ну и для серьезной работы с тегами через `DOM` **рекомендую** использовать библиотеки, такие как [phpQuery](http://habrahabr.ru/post/69149/) и [simpleHTMLDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: постановка задачи из жизни:

Мне нужно выводит например статью не всю, а часть и не фиксированное число символов, а там где пользователь поставит тег <--read more --->
Например, если этот тег не поставит то в новостной линии будет выводится полностью статья. Если стоит тег выводить информцию до этого тега.

Comment: Опять же, если тег у вас все время одинаковый, и другие варианты этого тега вы не рассматриваете, то [strstr][1] вам в помощь! Только третий параметр надо в `true` поставить

    $result = strstr($text, '<--read more --->', true);


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strstr.php